# How does QPE work if target register is in superposition of eigenstates?

Tags: grovers-algorithm, quantum-phase-estimation, superposition

In regular Quantum Phase Estimation algorithm the target register shall be in the eigenstate of the investigated operator. If it's the case, then applying controlled operator $U$ we can get its phase kicked back to the control register, and by applying inverse QFT can convert the phase difference into the amplitude difference in control register that can be measured:

$|x\rangle = CU|+\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|0\rangle|\psi\rangle + |1\rangle e^{i\theta}|\psi\rangle)$

$(H\otimes I)|x\rangle = \frac{1}{2}((1+e^{i\theta})|0\rangle + (1-e^{i\theta})|1\rangle)|\psi\rangle$

(where $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of operator $U$). Also for simplicity I assume that control register consists of only 1 qubit (and use Hadamard gate instead of iQFT) as the effect shall be the same for any size of control register.

But in some other algorithms (e.g. Quantum counting) the target register is in superposition of eigenstates, rather then in a particular eigenstate. In Quantum Counting it's in $|+\rangle^{\otimes n}$ which happens to be a superposition of 2 eigenstates. I tried to understand why it still works and it looks like it shouldn't work in case of some arbitrary superposition of eigenstates:

$|\psi\rangle = a|\psi_1\rangle + b|\psi_2\rangle$

$|x\rangle = CU|+\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|0\rangle(a|\psi_1\rangle + b|\psi_2\rangle) + |1\rangle (a|e^{i\theta_1}\psi_1\rangle + b|e^{i\theta_2}\psi_2\rangle)$

$(H\otimes I)|x\rangle =|0\rangle(a(1+e^{i\theta_1})|\psi_1\rangle +b(1+e^{i\theta_2})|\psi_2) + |1\rangle(a(1-e^{i\theta_1})|\psi_1\rangle +b(1-e^{i\theta_2})|\psi_2)$

or for clarity:

$$(H\otimes I)|x\rangle =\begin{bmatrix} a(1+e^{i\theta_1})|\psi_1\rangle +b(1+e^{i\theta_2})|\psi_2 \\ a(1-e^{i\theta_1})|\psi_1\rangle +b(1-e^{i\theta_2})|\psi_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Thus, the probability of measuring control register $x$ to $0$: $p(x=0)=|(a(1+e^{i\theta_1})|\psi_1\rangle +b(1+e^{i\theta_2})|\psi_2)|^2$ depends on $a,b,|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle$ and not just on $\theta$ as in the case of regular QPE.

It's my understanding that in case of Quantum Counting the choice of weights $a,b$ in superposition is such that applying controlled $U$ still provides the phase kickback, even though I can't replicate it. More general question is what conditions $a,b$ and probably $|\psi_1\rangle, |\psi_2\rangle$ must satisfy for the QPE on superposition to work?